# nested javascript function loses "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a nested function that loses the proper scope of "this"

```
if(tabNav === true){

$("." + tabNavClass).show();
tabNavItem.first().addClass("active");//active class on first li
tabNavItem.each(function(i){
    $(this).attr("rel",(i + 1));
});                         

tabNavItem.on("click", function(e){

    tabNavClick();
    //this works, but i don't want it defined here. i want it in the tabNavClick() function
    //var data = $(this).attr("rel");
    //console.log(data);
    e.preventDefault();

});             

}           


//tab nav function          
function tabNavClick(){

// REGISTERS UNDEFINED HERE B/C LOSES SCOPE OF "THIS". FIX?!                    
var that = $(this);
var data = that.attr("rel");
console.log(data);

tabNavItem.removeClass("active");//remove existing active class
```

};

I have tried `var that = $(this)`, but that doesn't work and i don't think .call would work in this scenario. how do i get `$(this).attr("rel");` to return the rel # value i want instead of `undefined`?

Comment: It looks like `tabNavClick` is already written like a click handler, so why not register it as such? :)

Comment: @Jack honestly, b/c i don't know what i'm doing. i'm trying to write my first plugin. i know what a click handler is, but how would registering it help me in this situation?

Comment: I've explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `$(this)` to the function

```
  tabNavClick($(this));

  function tabNavClick(obj){
     var that = obj;
     ....
```

additionally you can pass function tabNavClick as click handler and take the event

```
  tabNavItem.on("click",tabNavClick)

  function tabNavClick(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var that=$(this);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `tabNavClick()` to have the desired `this` value, then you need to specify that when you call it:

```
tabNavItem.on("click", function(e){

    tabNavClick.call(this);
    //this works, but i don't want it defined here. i want it in the tabNavClick() function
    //var data = $(this).attr("rel");
    //console.log(data);
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

The way a function is called determines the `this` value.  If it's not a method call and you're not using `.call()` or `.apply()`, then `this` will get reset on any function call.  In this case, you can use `tabNavClick.call(this)` to cause the `this` value to be what you want.

---

Of, you could just change `tabNavClick` to take an argument for the object to operate on:

```
tabNavItem.on("click", function(e){

    tabNavClick(this);
    //this works, but i don't want it defined here. i want it in the tabNavClick() function
    e.preventDefault();

});     

//tab nav function          
function tabNavClick(obj){

    var data = $(obj).attr("rel");
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: @jfriend00 both this and bipen's answer worked. thanks so much. i didn't think i could use .call here b/c all the examples i saw that used it only showed it being used in a prototypal inheritance example. do you have any good resources that i could read to get a better understanding of .call. I'm new to it and as you can tell, i don't have a firm grasp on it.

Comment: @heyjohnmurray - MDN is usually my first look for a reference.  See [.call() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).  It can be used for any function call.  You can search for anything on MDN in Google with a search like this: "MDN .call".  Note, I added a simpler second option to my answer too that is just a straight function call with an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass `tabNavClick` itself as the click handler:

```
tabNavItem.on("click", tabNavClick);
```

This would invoke `tabNavClick` in a way that `this` points to the item that's clicked on.

You can let `tabNavClick` return `false` to prevent the event from bubbling. Additionally, you could make `tabNavClick` accept the event as well:

```
function tabNavClick(e) {
    // ...
    e.preventDefault();
}
```